# GUI solving equations project

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a Matlab project in which I need to make a GUI that receives two mathematical functions from the user. I then need to find their intersection point, and then plot the two functions.

So, I have several questions:

1. Do you know of any algorithm I can use to find the intersection point? Of course I prefer one to which I can already find a Matlab code for in the internet. Also, I prefer it wouldn't be the Newton-Raphson method.
   I should point out I'm not allowed to use built in Matlab functions.
2. I'm having trouble plotting the functions. What I basically did is this:

   ```
   fun_f = get(handles.Function_f,'string');    
   fun_g = get(handles.Function_g,'string');    
   cla % To clear axes when plotting new functions    
   ezplot(fun_f);    
   hold on    
   ezplot(fun_g);    
   axis ([-20 20 -10 10]);
   ```

The problem is that sometimes, the axes limits do not allow me to see the other function. This will happen, if, for example, I will have one function as `log10(x)` and the other as `y=1`, the `y=1` will not be shown.
I have already tried using all the axis commands but to no avail. If I set the limits myself, the functions only exist in certain limits. I have no idea why.

3 . How do I display numbers in a static text? Or better yet, string with numbers?
I want to display something like `x0 = [root1]; x1 = [root2]`. The only solution I found was turning the roots I found into strings but I prefer not to.

As for the equation solver, this is the code I have so far. I know it is very amateurish but it seemed like the most "intuitive" way. Also keep in mind it is very very not finished (for example, it will show me only two solutions, I'm not so sure how to display multiple roots in one static text as they are strings, hence question #3).

```
function [Sol] = SolveEquation(handles)
fun_f = get(handles.Function_f,'string');
fun_g = get(handles.Function_g,'string');
f = inline(fun_f);
g = inline(fun_g);

i = 1;
Sol = 0;

for x = -10:0.1:10;
        if (g(x) - f(x)) >= 0 && (g(x) - f(x)) < 0.01
            Sol(i) = x;
            i = i + 1;
        end
end

solution1 = num2str(Sol(1));
solution2 = num2str(Sol(2));

set(handles.roots1,'string',solution1);
set(handles.roots2,'string',solution2);
```

The `if` condition is because the subtraction will never give me an absolute zero, and this seems to somewhat solve it, though it's really not perfect, sometimes it will give me more than two very similar solutions (e.g 1.9 and 2).
The range of `x` is arbitrary, chosen by me.

I know this is a long question, so I really appreciate your patience. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of `f(x)` and `g(x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

I think this is a more robust method for finding the roots given data at discrete points. Looking for when the difference between the functions changes sign, which corresponds to them crossing over.

```
S=sign(g(x)-f(x));
h=find(diff(S)~=0)
Sol=x(h);
```

If you can evaluate the function wherever you want there are more methods you can use, but it depends on the size of the domain and the accuracy you want as to what is best. For example, if you don't need a great deal of accurac, your `f` and `g` functions are simple to calculate, and you can't or don't want to use derivatives, you can get a more accurate root using the same idea as the first code snippet, but do it iteratively:

```
G=inline('sin(x)');
F=inline('1');
g=vectorize(G);
f=vectorize(F);
tol=1e-9;
tic()
x = -2*pi:.001:pi;
S=sign(g(x)-f(x));
h=find(diff(S)~=0); % Find where two lines cross over
Sol=zeros(size(h));
Err=zeros(size(h));
if ~isempty(h) % There are some cross-over points
    for i=1:length(h) % For each point, improve the approximation
        xN=x(h(i):h(i)+1);
        err=1;
        while(abs(err)>tol) % Iteratively improve aproximation
            S=sign(g(xN)-f(xN));
            hF=find(diff(S)~=0);
            xN=xN(hF:hF+1);
            [~,I]=min(abs(f(xN)-g(xN)));
            xG=xN(I);
            err=f(xG)-g(xG);
            xN=linspace(xN(1),xN(2),15);
        end
        Sol(i)=xG;
        Err(i)=f(xG)-g(xG);
    end
else % No crossover points - lines could meet at tangents
    [h,I]=findpeaks(-abs(g(x)-f(x)));
    Sol=x(I(abs(f(x(I))-g(x(I)))<1e-5));
    Err=f(Sol)-g(Sol)
end
% We also have to check each endpoint
if abs(f(x(end))-g(x(end)))<tol && abs(Sol(end)-x(end))>1e-12
    Sol=[Sol x(end)];
    Err=[Err g(x(end))-f(x(end))];
end
if abs(f(x(1))-g(x(1)))<tol && abs(Sol(1)-x(1))>1e-12
    Sol=[x(1) Sol];
    Err=[g(x(1))-f(x(1)) Err];
end
toc()
Sol
Err
```

This will "zoom" in to the region around each suspected root, and iteratively improve the accuracy. You can tweak the parameters to see whether they give better behaviour (the tolerance `tol`, the 15, number of new points to generate, could be higher probably).

**Question 2**

You would probably be best off avoiding `ezplot`, and using `plot`, which gives you greater control. You can vectorise inline functions so that you can evaluate them like anonymous functions, as I did in the previous code snippet, using

```
f=inline('x^2')
F=vectorize(f)
F(1:5)
```

and this should make plotting much easier:

```
plot(x,f(x),'b',Sol,f(Sol),'ro',x,g(x),'k',Sol,G(Sol),'ro')
```

**Question 3**

I'm not sure why you don't want to display your roots as strings, what's wrong with this:

```
text(xPos,yPos,['x0=' num2str(Sol(1))]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have to study your code as I am not familiar with some of the functions (like linspace). The displaying my roots as strings might be a problem (I'm still not sure about that) because I want to display in one static text "x0 = sol(1); x1 = sol(2)",etc... (after all there could be many solutions to the equation). How do I do such a thing? A for or a while loop? Do you think you have a better idea to display the roots, GUI-wise?

Comment: About your comment (didn't see it at first), f(x) and g(x) could be anything, ranging from a polynom to sin,cos and log. I don't need derivatives, fortunately.

Comment: once again, thank you for the code. It's nearly perfect, but it has one problem though. If one function is tangent to another, the Sol matrix will be empty. For example, it will happen if f = x^2 + 2x and g = -1. or f = sin(x) and g = 1.

Comment: That is a tricky case to manage. I've edited my answer, see how it goes.